# How to launch Blackberry World from an application? [BB10]

Tags: javascript, blackberry-10

I am trying to open the blackberry world in BB10 OS from my application,but i dint find a way i have done that for earlier versions by taking below as reference.

[How to launch AppWorld from an application? [BlackBerry]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673706/how-to-launch-appworld-from-an-application-blackberry)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/invoking_core_apps.html

Comment: @KonradLindenbach make it an answer, so he can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this for documentation on invoking core apps: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/invoking_core_apps.html